# Libreoffice Writer cannot access documents on Synology NFS share

Tags: libreoffice, nfs, nas

some days ago, I installed LibreOffice 6.4.6.2 on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on a Lenovo Ideapad 5.15. So far, everything seems to be running nicely with one rather large exception.

Together with my Laptop I am using a Synology DS215j running on DSM 6.2.4-25556. On that NAS, there are a couple of shared folders, mounted via fstab entries following the schema:

SomeIPv4address:/volume1/fum /mnt/fum nfs auto,user,defaults,rsize=32768,wsize=32768,tcp,intr 0 0

using nfs 3 and AUTH_SYS authentication.

Again, everything seems to be running nicely. However, when I am trying to access files on the shares with LibreOfficeWriter LibreOffice freezes. By accessing I mean trying to open documents in Nautilus, trying to do so via the 'open' menu entry or trying to save newly created files to the share. After a quick check, Calc seems to be having the same issue.

Concerning permissions, there is the following information:

ls -ln / | grep mnt:

drwxr-xr-x 7 0 0 4096 Apr 10 14:34 mnt

ls -ln /mnt | grep fum:

drwxrwxrwx 7 0 0 4096 Apr 10 23:37 fum

id:

uid=1027(username) gid=100(users) Gruppen=100(users),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),46(plugdev),120(lpadmin),131(lxd),132(sambashare),1000(username)

Is there somebody out there, who could help my with that problem? I found several related requests throughout the Internet. All of these seem to be concerned with the SMB protocol, though.

So, thanks a lot in advance! I am looking forward to your answers!

Best Regards,

Firewing

Solved:
Use fixed port for nlockmgr and enable that port in firewall settings

Comment: I am using a Synology NAS DS220j mounted in fstab in 20.04.2 LTS but not as NFS but using SAMBA share with cifs. I have absolutely no problem accessing LO Calc files on the NAS (and I guess the same will be so with Writer). version of LO= 7.0.4.2

Comment: not able to comment bc no reputation.... i'm glad you posted this issue. i have the same issue but with nfs 3 on truenas and ubuntu mate and kubuntu 20.04 and have been searching for an answer. I think this takes synology out of the question and leaves us with nfs and ubuntu. something changed in the last few months because it all worked fine previously. FWIW it also happens on libvirt with an nfs mount. i was suspecting it is apparmor, but not sure how to dignose.

Answer (score 1):

Just citing from [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/LibreOffice#Hanging_when_using_NFSv3_shares):

> **Hanging when using NFSv3 shares**
>
> If LibreOffice hangs when trying to open or save a document located on
> a NFSv3 share, try prepending the following lines with a # in
> /usr/lib/libreoffice/program/soffice:
>
> ```
> # file locking now enabled by default
> SAL_ENABLE_FILE_LOCKING=1
> export SAL_ENABLE_FILE_LOCKING
> ```

That worked for me.

Comment: This was a great case of RTFM on your part. Thank you